# How to get a list of objects where the second object has the status ''true'?

Tags: javascript

Please tell me. There is an Api request and in response I receive an array of the form:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "rspa": [
    {
      "address": "FB2A23D4-554E9",
      "def": false,
      "tk": false
    },
    {
      "address": "FA0EBFB496DA-C5465A8D",
      "def": true,
      "tk": false
    },
    {
      "address": "FA0434B496DA-C5465A8D",
      "def": true,
      "tk": false
    }
  ]
}
```

How to loop through a list of addresses (address object) where the object is "def": true?

```
myArray = data.rspa
var addrs = myArray.map(function(elem){
   return elem.address;
   }).join(",");
   console.log(addrs);
```

It works but displays all addresses. Result FB2A23D4-554E9,FA0EBFB496DA-C5465A8D,FA0434B496DA-C5465A8D

```
myArray = data.data.rspa
 var idToLookFor = 'true';
 var foundObject = myArray.filter(function(item) {
   return item.def === idToLookFor;
 })[0].address;
console.log(foundObject.address);
});
```

Gives an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` and `map` do two different things, and what you want is a combination of *both*.  When you used `map` it "worked", except the results weren't *filtered*.  Just `filter` them first, *then* `map` them into the structure you want.  Then `join` and output the result.

(Additionally, you want to use `true` instead of `'true'` as the value to filter on, otherwise comparing with `===` won't return anything.)

```js
var data = {
  "status": true,
  "rspa": [
    {
      "address": "FB2A23D4-554E9",
      "def": false,
      "tk": false
    },
    {
      "address": "FA0EBFB496DA-C5465A8D",
      "def": true,
      "tk": false
    },
    {
      "address": "FA0434B496DA-C5465A8D",
      "def": true,
      "tk": false
    }
  ]
};

var myArray = data.rspa;
var idToLookFor = true;

var result = myArray.filter(function(item) {
  return item.def === idToLookFor;
}).map(function(elem){
  return elem.address;
}).join(",");

console.log(result);
```

---

As an aside... You don't even need `idToLookFor` in this case.  If `result.def` is `true` then you can just return that value from the `filter` callback.

Comment: And without brackets it is easier to read trivial filter/maps `const result = myArray.filter(item => item.def).map(item => item.address).join(",");`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because you don't handle the case where def is false

```
var foundObject = myArray.find(function(item) {
  return item.def === true;
});
foundObject ? console.log(foundObject.adress) : console.log("not found");
```